# In what order do Linux SCSI disk IDs appear?

Tags: linux

In what order do Linux SCSI disk IDs appear? I recently found out that sometimes, `hdc1` and `hdd1` come without `hdb1`. What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

This scheme can be found here https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/installation-guide/i386/device-names.html. HDA is your master on primary controller, hdb is a slave. For SCSI it should be sdX.

Comment: Hi tdi, thankx for your concern. But here is my situation, I am writing a c program in linux and in the program I am mounting 2 usb devices attached to 2 specific ports in the computer. (eg : I have to mount the usb attached to the left port in to /mnt/left  and the right port to /mnt/right) and the attachment order of those devices may differ (eg: left port usb may or may not be attached before the right.)   In this case what should i do?

Comment: You can use another method. In newer linux there is a way to uniquely identify disc device. Check this link http://wikis.sun.com/display/BigAdmin/Using+Disk+Labels+on+Linux+File+Systems. In general you can access diks by their ID. /dev/disk/by-id. Aslso by path and uuid.